# Как дождаться включения wifi?

Tags: android

При включении моего приложения включается wifi так:

```
WifiManager Wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    Wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

Так как моё приложение браузер, то до включения wifi в нем делать нечего. Поэтому я решил использовать круговой прогресс бар, но ничего не получается.

Comment: Вы уверены, что интернет в телефоне берется только из вайфая?

Comment: Вы уверены, что включать вайфай за пользователя — это хорошая идея?

Comment: @zelta, так как я пришу это приложение для, я считаю это приемлемым.